# Do i require distribution provisioning profile for notification service extension for iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, provisioning-profile, unnotificationserviceextension

I am not getting proper documentation for Notification Service Extension's provisioning profile. 
But as per my knowledge, the Notification Service Extension has it's own bundle id, it must be set up with it's own App ID and provisioning profile.

Please clear this doubt that do i need to use distribution provisioning profile for notification service extension or not?

Comment: Is this push notification service, then if I have got your question right try to just create a APNS distribution cert on your dev-member center and install the same on your machine that will compile the app. Make sure the exported p12 for the cert is given to your server guy with the password so the notification can be triggered to APNS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By going through the docs i found that with different bundle id's we need to create different profiles.

I solved my problem by creating two profiles. I hope this will help others.

Comment: Hi Abhishel you mean to say if i have three different target extension, So i have to just create the distribution certificate for all of them ??.. and then upload the app for distribution